# Does this code have the correct output for this question

Tags: sql, ms-access

The question asked is: Report the nations where the average yield of the shares exceeds the average yield of all shares

I have a solution but I am unsure if it answers the question. I only received one output and I'm not sure if i need multiple

```
SELECT Nations.nationName, 
AVG(dividend/price*100) AS Yield
FROM Shares, Nations
WHERE Shares.nationID=Nations.ID
GROUP BY Nations.nationName
HAVING AVG(dividend/price*100)>
(SELECT AVG(dividend/price*100) FROM Shares);
```

My output only shows one result, i'm just wondering if this should be the outcome.
I'll provide the previous table and my output [image: Output of code shown here]
output of the previous table that is required to get this [image: output of the previous table that is required to get this]

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with the UK data which is causing it's average yield value to be too high (753% shouldn't be possible) and that is probably causing the overall average to be higher than all other countries average yield, hence only one row in the output

Comment: United Kingdom is only country that will meet criteria. Why output shows 753.04 instead of 7.53 is the mystery. I never set formatting in tables.

Comment: I fixed it by removing the *100, it now shows 7.53. With this issue fixed, the outcome seems ok?

Comment: @analliquid Your chosen username may be offensive to some users; perhaps consider whether other people will perceive it how you intended.

Comment: Move your HAVING SELECT to the top and eyeball the results

Comment: If you have only four countries, then it is not unreasonable that only one is above the weighted average.

Answer (score 1):

When Percentage formatting is applied to the column, the result will be automatically multiplied by `100` when displayed, i.e. a value of `0.25` will be displayed as `25%`; as such, either remove the formatting or remove the `100` multiplier from your code.

---

I would also suggest using an `inner join` over a Cartesian Product, i.e.:

```sql
select n.nationname, avg(s.dividend/s.price) as yield
from shares s inner join nations n on s.nationid = n.id
group by n.nationname
```

---

As for the correctness of your query, you can easily check this by calculating the average yield of all shares either manually or using a separate query, and then identifying which nations should be output by your query.